# React Native - How to improve responsiveness while ListView is loading

Tags: react-native

I have a list view I'm loading with lots of data.  While the data is loading I would like other elements, a toolbar for example, to be responsive.  Sample code is below, I find that for each 100 items the toolbar is unresponsive for an additional second.  My list will be over 1000 items.

I tried some of the performance suggestions but I wasn't able to tune it properly.  Any suggestions?

I would like for the 'toolbar' to be responsive to touches right away.  I'm happy to do paging if that is required, but I wanted to see if others have tuned this and have some suggestions.

```
    'use strict';

    let _ = require('underscore');
    let React = require('react-native');
    let {Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, ListView, ScrollView} = React;

    let Toolbar = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function () {
        return {
          isSearching: false
        }
      },
      _onSearch: function () {
        this.setState({ isSearching: true })
      },
      _onCancelSearch: function () {
        this.setState({ isSearching: false })
      },
      render: function () {
        let toSearchToolbar =
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={this._onSearch}>
            <View>
              <Text>Click to Search</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>

        let searchingToolbar =
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={this._onCancelSearch}>
            <View>
              <Text>Cancel</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>

        let toolbar = (this.state.isSearching) ? searchingToolbar : toSearchToolbar;

        return toolbar;
      }
    });

    let List = React.createClass({
      propTypes: {
        data: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
      },
      getInitialState: function () {
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
        return {
          dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.data),
        };
      },
      _renderRow: function (rowData) {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>{rowData}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      },
      render: function () {
        return (
          <ScrollView>
            <ListView
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={this._renderRow}
              initialListSize={10}
              scrollRenderAheadDistance={100}
              removeClippedSubviews={true}
              />
          </ScrollView>
        );
      },
    });

    let data = _.range(0, 1000).reverse()

    let Main = React.createClass({
      render: () => {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Toolbar/>
            <List data={data}/>
          </View>
        );
      }
    });

    let styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1
      }
    });

    module.exports = Main
```

Comment: try paginating .. your initial query should return a limited number of entries. then create a handler for the listview's onEndReached property. this should load the next batch once the user scrolls unseen data.

Comment: You can try the component SGList. It is a slightly more optimized version in terms of memory and speed

Comment: @boredgames thx, I'm reserving pagination as a last resort as this loads fine in native android if I use the ViewHolder pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest version of React Native (< 0.14.0) disable JS Dev Mode.

- Open device menu through a shake or CTRL-M in emulator
- Dev Settings
- Disable JS Dev Mode

It performs.  Whew.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to use the onChangeVisibleRows callback to get a list of visible rows and render only the content in those rows.

Comment: Like paging, I'm reserving this as a last resort.  If there is no other way to have an app with more than 100 items in the list perform well I may need to add this as a work-around.