# Filtering ListView with large number of rows

Tags: react-native

Trying to implement fast filtering of ListView in react native. Currently I'm filtering the DataSource to achieve this. It works, but causes big performance problems. The problem is following :

1. There is a ListView with 100 items in it. All of them are rendered
2. Filter is being applied which shrinks it to, say, 2 items
3. When the filter is cleared and DataSource goes back to initial 100 items
   ListView re-renders 98 items causing big performance problems
   (ListView performance while bulk rendering new rows is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030017/react-native-how-to-improve-responsiveness-while-listview-is-loading) )

Am I missing something here?

EDIT: added rnplay sample app to demonstrate the approach I'm currently using https://rnplay.org/apps/szko6Q

Comment: Questions without code sample gets less attention, Please post your code sample & ask a question related to the provided code.

Comment: maybe calculate what fits on the screen and render only those items, detect scrolling and render the remaining items as the user scrolls. (you can also remove the ones that scrolls out of the screen, there is an experimental prop for this called removeClippedSubviews)

Answer (score 1):

While rendering user these below mentioned properties

```
<ListView
   removeClippedSubviews={true}
   renderRow={this.renderRow}
   dataSource={this.getDataSource()}
   renderScrollComponent={(props) =><React.RecyclerViewBackedScrollView {...props}/>}
   style={{overflow:'hidden'}}
   renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}/>
```